# How to filter one source to three different set using RIA?

Tags: silverlight, ria

I defined a DomainDataSource in the XAML:

```
<dds:DomainDataSource x:Name="ddsPayroll" QueryName="GetEnPrcsQ" AutoLoad="True" LoadSize="20" PageSize="20">
  <dds:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
      <RIASrv:PayrollSrv />
  </dds:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>

  <dds:DomainDataSource.SortDescriptors>
      <filter:SortDescriptor Direction="Descending" PropertyPath="wProcessId" />
  </dds:DomainDataSource.SortDescriptors>
</dds:DomainDataSource>
```

In the record set returned, there is a column named "status".

I have 3 different listbox controls.

I need to assign `status=1` in `listbox1`, `status=2` in `listbox2`, and `status=3` in `listbox3`. Is there any way to do this in XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use three [CollectionViewSource](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=392) objects. Each one of them should have its Source property bound to the DataView property of the DomainDataSource. For each CollectionViewSource you will create a Filter delegate that will filter out the appropriate items for each one of your listboxes.